# How do I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix. I have tried to solve it myself but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Here's the matrix:

$$
B=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
5 & -2 & -6 \\
-2 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & -1 & -2
\end{array}\right]
$$

I know that the matrix has eigenvalues 1 and 3. But I'm not sure how to find a basis for each eigenspace.

I think I have to find the null space of B-λI to find the basis for each eigenspace.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Begin with writing down the definition of "eigenspace for the eigenvalue 3" (for instance), and translate that into equations.

Comment: @AnneBauval I know eigenspace is defined as the set of all eigenvectors of T corresponding to the same eigenvalue, together with the zero vector. But the definition doesn't help me much unfortunately. I've been struggling with vector spaces and eigenspaces for 2 days. I know that the determinant of a characteristic polynomial equal to 0 gives us our eigenvalues.

Comment: Write down (in terms of equations on $x,y,z$) the definition of "$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $B$ for the eigenvalue $3$".

Comment: @podiki Yes, that's not a problem. A pretty huge leap from asking if I'm not understanding something in chapter 5 to asking if I don't understand something so rudimentary as a concept in chapter 1.

Comment: Related to [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4697099/89922) also about the same matrix $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have the eigenvalues, you'll need to use the definitions to generate eigenspaces.

If $(\lambda, x)$ is an eigenpair for $A$ - that is, $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding the eigenvalue $\lambda$ - then we should have $$Ax - \lambda x = (A - \lambda I)x = 0.$$

This means that $x \in \mathrm{Nul} (A - \lambda I)$ - that is, $x$ is in the null space of the linear map $A - \lambda I$.

So, to find the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda,$ you must solve the equations $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$ for a particular $\lambda.$

In summary:

1. Find the zeros of the characteristic polynomial $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0.$
2. For each of the eigenvalues $\lambda,$ solve the equation $(A - \lambda I)x = 0.$ (That is, substitute each eigenvalue to create a new matrix.)
3. (Sanity check.) For each eigenvector $v,$ check by multiplying $Av.$ You should get $\lambda v$ in the end.

I'll illustrate with the case $\lambda = 1$ for this matrix which you have called $B$. (Note that the name does not matter.) We form the augmented matrix $[ B - I \ | \ 0 ]$ and place it into reduced row echelon form. I leave the details to you, to see that we obtain the equation (because two rows are zero) $$v_1 -\frac{1}{2}v_2 - \frac{3}{2}v_3 = 0.$$

Note that $v_1$ is a basic variable and $v_2, v_3$ are free. So, set $v_2 = 2, v_3 = 2.$ Then $v_1 = 4,$ so an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ is $(4, 2, 2)$. Now, we check by doing the multiplication of $Bv$, where $B$ is the original matrix and $v$ is the supposed eigenvector:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
5 & -2 & -6 \\
-2 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & -1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
2 \\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
2 \\
2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

This verifies that this is indeed an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Hello Sean, thanks. Is this correct? This is when I plug in lambda = 1, i.e. the eigenvalue. $$\begin{bmatrix} 5-1 & -2 & -6\\ -2 & 2-1 & 3\\ 2 & -1 & -2-1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and likewise when I plug in the eigenvalue = 3, I get: $$\begin{bmatrix}5-3 & -2 & -6\\ -2 & 2-3 & 3\\ 2 & -1 & -2-3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That's exactly what you're supposed to do. Now everything else follows. Follow your gut. Note that everything I wrote is a general process, and if you follow the definitions and do the sanity check, things should line up.

Comment: I am not sure how the third step is supposed to be executed. What is the eigenvector v, and what is the matrix A? You mean that there's a 3x1 matrix v that I need to multiply A with, in which I get a resulting vector v which is the eigenvector?

Comment: Hello Sean, note that [the OP already did steps 1 and 2 three days ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697099).

Comment: Hello OP, I answered [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4699141/386889) to your previous comment (and to that previous post).

Comment: Noted. @Bishop_1, next time, please do not make a new question for the exact same problem. Instead edit that post or patiently wait for it to be seen.